# In uninstall function of bootstrap, re-import?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, uninstallation, firefox-addon-restartless

In the `uninstall` part of my bootstrapped addons I do some important stuff. I delete any files it created and all preferences. However this uses some services.

This is an example of one of my `uninstall` procedures:

```
function uninstall(aData, aReason) {
    if (aReason == ADDON_UNINSTALL) { //have to put this here because uninstall fires on upgrade/downgrade too
        //this is real uninstall
        Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
        Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');
        Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
        //if custom images were used lets delete them now
        var customImgPrefs = ['customImgIdle', 'customImgLoading'];
        [].forEach.call(customImgPrefs, function(n) {
            //cant check the pref i guess because its probably unintialized or deleted before i used have a `if(prefs[n].value != '') {`
            //var normalized = OS.Path.normalize(prefs[n].value);
            //var profRootDirLoc = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, OS.Path.basename(normalized));
            var profRootDirLoc = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'throbber-restored-' + n);
            var promiseDelete = OS.File.remove(profRootDirLoc);
            console.log('profRootDirLoc', profRootDirLoc)
            promiseDelete.then(
                function() {
                    Services.prompt.alert(null, 'deleted', 'success on ' + n);
                },
                function(aRejReas) {
                    console.warn('Failed to delete copy of custom throbber ' + n + ' image for reason: ', aRejReas);
                    Services.prompt.alert(null, 'deleted', 'FAILED on ' + n);
                }
            );
        });

        Services.prefs.deleteBranch(prefPrefix);
    }
```

The reason I post rather than test is because I tested and it worked but is there any special cases? Like what if addon was disabled, browser restarted, and then user opened addon manager then uninstalled. Special cases like these and any others? Do they require me to import all my stuff again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uninstall` wlll be called regardless of whether the add-on was previously enabled or not, and regardless of whether the add-on was compatible or not, as long at the add-on is still present.
It won't be called, of course, if the user manually deleted the add-on XPI (or unpacked directory) from their profile while the browser wasn't running, because then on the next start there is nothing left to call.

This also means that `uninstall` might be the first (and only) add-on function called. If the add-on was always disabled right from the browser start and it is then disabled, then there won't be any other calls. This is important to be aware of. Consider the following contrived example.

```
var myId;

Cu.reportError("global exec"); // Thiw will be always run, as well.

function startup(data) {
  myId = data.id,
}
function uninstall() {
  Cu.reportError(myId); // might be undefined if startup never ran.
}
```

So, there are three and a half special "things" to consider:

1. `uninstall` does not run when the XPI is manually removed while the browser is not running. 2. When uinstalled properly, then `uninstall` will *always* be run.
2. .. even if no other add-on functions were called prior to that.
3. This also means that any global code in your `bootstrap.js` will also run on `uninstall`, as a consequent of loading `bootstrap.js`.

Upon cursory inspection, your code does not seem to rely on anything initialized elsewhere, so it should be fine.

I'd like to point out however, that it is generally considered a bad idea to remove user configuration upon uninstall if not specifically instructed by the user to do so. Same goes for configuration files and user data files. If you do so, you should ask before.
Users will regularly uninstall and then reinstall stuff, only to find their carefully crafted preferences, etc. are gone otherwise.

Comment: "This also means that any global code in your bootstrap.js will also run on uninstall, as a consequent of loading bootstrap.js." YES! Thanks that makes so much sense.

Comment: Yeah I should at least prompt them Im removing all prefs and files. It's just when I uninstall software, I want every trace of it gone. If i want it temporarily off, Ill disable it. I install then uninstall so many add-ons, it causes all this bloat and crap in my browser :( I have random files my gosh, so annoying. I think AMO should make an effort to make users and especially devs treat uninstall like software uninstall on OS. Otheriwse the "Reset Firefox" feature needs to be used, and my history and stuff is too valuble to reset it all.

Comment: OS-level software uninstall won't remove prefs, usually. For the same reason. I see why you like software to remove stuff on uninstall, and I can actually sympathize with that. But to a lot of users this will come unexpected, so you cannot meet everybody's expectations. So either do the least destructive thing (don't delete data) or ask before you do something destructive (or have an undo function, but I don't think this would be an option in this scenario).